# How can I Implement Map and Bind operations under the same name for Maybe and Nullable?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a `Maybe` type that I use in code I control as the reference type equivalent of `Nullable`.

The definition is `struct Maybe<T> where T : class` and it has the usual `HasValue` and `Value` methods.

I want to provide both `Map` and `Bind` operations (with the same behavior as the F# [Option.map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340461.aspx) and [Option.bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353901.aspx)), and I want to implement both under the same name `IfHasValue`.

I want to implement `IfHasValue()` not just for `Maybe`, but also for `Nullable`, and allow mapping (and binding) from a class to a struct and vica versa.

Essentially I want all of these tests to compile and pass:

```
var maybeValue = Maybe.WithValue("some string");
int? nullableValue = 42;

maybeValue.IfHasValue(x => x.Length).ShouldEqual(11);
maybeValue.IfHasValue(x => (int?)x.Length).ShouldEqual(11);

maybeValue.IfHasValue(x => x + " more").Value.ShouldEqual("some string more");
maybeValue.IfHasValue(x => Maybe.WithValue(x + " more")).Value.ShouldEqual("some string more");

nullableValue.IfHasValue(x => x + 1).ShouldEqual(43);
nullableValue.IfHasValue(x => (int?)x + 1).ShouldEqual(43);

nullableValue.IfHasValue(x => x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).Value.ShouldEqual("42");
nullableValue.IfHasValue(x => Maybe.WithValue(x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))).Value.ShouldEqual("42");
```

The issue I've run in to is that in this case

```
maybeValue.IfHasValue(x => Maybe.WithValue(x + " more")).Value.ShouldEqual("some string more");
```

type inference can't determine which of these two overloads is intended

```
public static Maybe<TOut> IfHasValue<TIn, TOut>(this Maybe<TIn> maybe, Func<TIn, Maybe<TOut>> selector)
    where TIn : class where TOut : class {}

// Note that in the full implementation I use the delegate trick to avoid
// this overload conflicting with the `TOut : class` version, but I omitted it
// since it's not needed for the overloads under discussion here.
public static TOut? IfHasValue<TIn, TOut>(this Maybe<TIn> maybe, Func<TIn, TOut> selector)
    where TIn : class where TOut : struct {}
```

because my `Maybe` type is a struct and I can't inform the compiler that if the result of the selector is a `Maybe` then the `Maybe` (first) overload should always be used because a `Nullable<Maybe<>>` is redundant.

Interestingly the compiler seems to already do this for `Nullable` ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)):

> **where T: struct** The type argument must be a value type. Any value type except Nullable can be specified. See Using Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide) for more information.

but I assume that's baked in and there's no way to get it to treat my `Maybe` type the same way.

Is there any way I can get type inference to work in this case?

Workarounds I've considered but am not particularly happy with:

- Having a different name for the `Map` and `Bind` versions.
- Requiring explicitly specifying type parameters in this case.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to restrict `Maybe` to reference types, you should make it work for any type and provide conversion methods to/from nullable structs.

Comment: That's an interesting point. Our current reasoning for limiting our `Maybe` type to reference type is that there's already a `Maybe` type for value types, `Nullable`, and it's better than our `Maybe` type because it's part of the language and the compiler is aware of it: the syntax is nicer, it's used by other libraries, it lifts common operators, etc. so it seems a shame to abandon it just because it doesn't support reference types.

Comment: If there's something that's unclear about my question please let me know what it is and I'll improve it. I tried to be extremely clear about what I'm trying to do, why, and the problem I've run in to, so I'm not sure what the confusion is.

Comment: The problem is that `Nullable<T>` is not a 'Maybe for value types' - it has no map/bind/join operators, and is treated specially by the compiler. You will also have to propagate the `T: class` constraint in every method you want to consume `Maybe<T>` values in. If you are going to create your own maybe type, I suggest you use it everywhere in your code and only convert to/from nullable types at the boundaries. Generic constraints are not used for overload resolution so doing what you're trying to do here is going to cause you problems.